# jQuery ajax related issue

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out, whats I am doing wrong in following code:

```
$(function() {
   $(".alert").live('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).closest("tr").attr("id")
      var info = 'id=' + id;
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "http://localhost/app/ajax.php?act=alert",
         data: info,
         success: function(Response){
           }
      });
   alert(Response);
   $(this).hide();
   return false;
   });
});
```

`Return false` is not working.

HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="alert">Alert</a>
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do and what does not work? It seems the code is not in success callback... it probably "does not work" because `Response` is not defined (so it throws an error. Look at the console.

Comment: @Felix Kling its not working correct, it redirect page to # , please even check my html code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is *by definition* **asynchronous**.

When your `$.ajax` call returns the HTTP request will still be getting processed, and therefore `Response` will not yet be filled.

Put the `alert(Response)` call inside your `success` callback to see how it should work.

Comment: yes working now, thanks, so can you clearify more, what i was doing wrong?

Comment: you were expecting `Response` to contain a value before the callback had ever been called.